# Which filament is best for printing parts that will endue a constant load for a long period of time?

Tags: filament, abs, petg, filament-choice

I thought the answer was ABS, but I read about how some people used it to print parts that were used in plumbing, and they failed when put under constant load, and some said that PETG is better for this application. I want to print bases for my table legs, would PETG be a better material to use?

Comment: source for ABS failing? it's quite important to know the source to get further details. Maybe (likely) it was ABS+

Comment: Table base means high compressive strength. Even if they are for a piano, any material will do. PLA will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

PETG creeps more than ABS/ASA, so I think you should still pick those. Be sure to print them hot and in a closed chamber, but you are loading in compression, so you won't have big issues.

See these tests for creep:

The conclusion is that ASA deforms in the beginning and then it stops. PETG in tensile keeps stretching, but in compression seems fine.

I think ABS is still the best, especially if you use a pure ABS, not an ABS+. Rather than an ABS+ use ASA.

Since it's not critical and if it breaks it's no big deal (likely it will get thinner with time), PETG is an alternative you can try.

Comment: PETG creeps but PET doesn't.

Comment: It creeps but not much

Answer (score 0):

For table leg stoppers and things like sandwich signs I use TPU, never had a problem with them yet. They're flexible and strong. Which means you can design them to insert easily and lock themselves in place. They're forgiving if your table leg is not quite evenly prepared at the bottom.

The only problem I can think of which would also apply to any other material is if they have to deal with a sharp edge.